# How do I go to the first error?

Tags: visual-studio

When I introduce a breaking change, a list of compilation errors appears at the Error List. Is there a keyboard way to go to the first error? (Shortcut or some command I can associate one). The View.NextError command, associated to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F8</kbd> by default, leaves me at the SECOND error of the list. Also, for the same reason, when I correct an error and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> I don't go to the "next" error (now at the first place) but to the second next.

**EDIT:** It seems that there is no native command to go to the first error, so a working solution would be to create a macro that executes View.NextError and View.PreviousError and associate a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: On a sidenote this seems to be fixed for VS2012. There F8 gets you to the first error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me, it only works if I press <kbd>F8</kbd> followed by <kbd>Shift+F8</kbd> to go back to the previous error.

Comment: An easy way to remember this shortcut is to think "F8" = "Fatal" Error.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>F4</kbd> does this.
You can download the VS 2010 Keybinding posters in PDF format [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=92CED922-D505-457A-8C9C-84036160639F&displaylang=en).